# How to solve these Maven Errors: classpath error: unable to find.., ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for

Tags: maven, proxy, eclipse-indigo

I tried to use Springsource Tool Suite (STS) but I had so many compile errors.

```
classpath error: unable to find org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint (check that aspectjrt.jar is in your classpath)  SpringApp       Unknown Java Problem

ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer cglib:cglib-nodep:pom:2.2 from http://maven.springframework.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-maven-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact cglib:cglib-nodep:pom:2.2 from/to spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release): null to http://maven.springframework.org/release/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.pom   pom.xml /SpringApp  line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:pom:1.2 from http://maven.springframework.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-maven-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:pom:1.2 from/to spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release): null to http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/codehaus/mojo/aspectj-maven-plugin/1.2/aspectj-maven-plugin-1.2.pom   pom.xml /SpringApp  line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem
```

I found so many question here in stackoverflow but no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set the IDE's proxy settings plus the Maven's setings.xml proxy settings.